# "Production" vs. "manufacturing"

Tags: terminology, technical

What are the connotations of *production* and *manufacturing*? In what situation would you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in how the item in question is produced.

[Manufacture](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manufacture)

> To make or process (a raw material) into a finished product, especially by means of a large-scale industrial operation.
>
> To make or process (a product), especially with the use of industrial machines.
>
> To create, produce, or turn out in a mechanical manner: "His books seem to have been manufactured rather than composed" (Dwight Macdonald).
>
> To concoct or invent; fabricate: manufacture an excuse.

See how industrial machines or mechanical way are explicitly mentioned in every meaning

[Production](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/production) is more general.

> The act or process of producing: timber used for the production of lumber and paper.
>
> The fact or process of being produced: a movie going into production.
>
> The creation of value or wealth by producing goods and services.
>
> The total output, as of a commodity: increased production at the plant.
>
> Something produced; a product: "Of all the productions of land, milk is perhaps 
>   the most perishable" (Adam Smith).
>
> A work of art or literature.
>
> A work produced for the stage, screen, television, or radio.
>
> A staging or presentation of a theatrical work: a new Broadway production of a musical.
>
> A situation or display that is exaggerated or unduly complicated: made a production out of the birthday party.